# Defined macro not recognized

Tags: c++

I have the following code in my Eclipse project

```
#pragma once

#ifdef WIN32 // Compiler enters here !
    #define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
#else
    #include <cmath>
#endif

#ifndef INFINITY
    #define INFINITY FLT_MAX
#endif

inline float Radians(float deg)
{
    return ((float)M_PI/180.f) * deg;
}
```

Problem is that I'm getting the following error from the compiler

```
Luzoso.hpp:22:20: error: 'M_PI' was not declared in this scope
     return ((float)M_PI/180.f) * deg;
```

I don't understand what the problem might be. I built the project with CMake using `ECLIPSE CDT4 - MinGW Makefiles` as the generator. Any advise?

Comment: You might try `__MINGW32__` instead of `WIN32`...?  Or perhaps `_WIN32`?  You can try `-E` to see compiler output after pre-processing, then search that for `M_PI`.

Comment: Your post doesn't indicate which condition in the `#ifdef` was triggered.  Was it the `WIN32` condition or not?

Comment: Yes it is define. Well at least that's what I think since Eclipse's editor shows the code as active. Is there a way to be 100% sure what part the #if-else the compiler enters to?

Comment: My crystal ball tells me `#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES` is missing (old MinGW, improperly configured CMake, ...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WIN32` isn't the correct macro. It's actually [`_WIN32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx). Either way, that's a macro defined by Visual Studio C++, but you're using [MinGW](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Compilers/) so the actual macro to check for is `__MINGW32__` or (64). This still is the wrong way to do things, since [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hwaceh6.aspx) requires:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES // for C++
#include <cmath>
```

In order to access the math constants. [MinGW already does this](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CriticalResearchFailure).