# CMake project for Eclipse+MinGW using Visual Studio defines instead of GCC

Tags: c++, cmake

My problem is very much related the post
[Defined macro not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106806/defined-macro-not-recognized)

I wrote a CMakeLists file to be able to build my project for OS X (Eclipse mostly but sometimes used Xcode) and Windows (Visual Studio). The issue showed up today when creating my project for Windows + MinGW. I was using the defined `_WIN32` to enable some functions when I was in windows, i.e.

```
bool Normal::HasNaNs() const
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    return _isnan(x) || _isnan(y) || _isnan(z);
#else
    return isnan(x) || isnan(y) || isnan(z);
#endif
}
```

However, with the combo Eclipse+MinGW the code is entering the **ifdef** part instead of (what I was hoping/thinking should be correct) entering the **else** part. I think Visual is the only one having the `_isnan()` function.
So, what would be a more robust way to check for Windows+VS, Windows+MinGW, OSX ?

Comment: Your other question was about a non-standard extension (`M_PI` isn't part of C). `isnan` IS part of C++, but C++11. If you are using CMake, these preprocessor defines are the entirely wrong approach. Why aren't you doing this at the CMake level?

Comment: I read just enough to get my CMake file going to create projects. My project has changed and new needs have arisen. Could you provide a link where I can read and learn how to achieve this at CMake level?

Comment: Everything you wanted to know but was afraid to ask: [Pre-defined Compiler Macros](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home/)

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046114/in-cmake-how-can-i-test-if-the-compiler-is-clang

Answer (score 2):

`_MSC_VER` is the best way to check if you're being compiled by Visual Studio:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx

For checking for MinGW (please see comment for more info), you can use:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#ifdef __MINGW32__
```

as per this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17493838/493106

and then `__APPLE__` for os x.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2166491/493106

Comment: Note that `__GNUC__` is [also defined for llvm](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1959615/2436175), so it's not always sufficient to understand unambiguously if the compiler is really gcc/g++ (although here we are speaking more specifically about MinGW)

Comment: Good to know, I'll point to your comment in the answer just in case anyone wasn't looking..